# Value is not getting pass from view to action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i am new in mvc. i have design a form and when i am click the submit button then right action method is calling but form field's value are not getting pass.

here is my view code

```
<div id="mydiv">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Game", FormMethod.Post, new { @Id = "Form1" }))
{
    <table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>Name :</td>
        <td><input name="name" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>Salary :</td>
        <td><input name="salary" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Save" /> </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
}
</div>
```

here is my action method

```
 public ActionResult Save(string str1, string str2)
 {
     return View("Message");
 }
```

when save is getting called the `str1` & `str2` is being `null` please help me to pass value and also discuss various trick to pass value from view to action method. thanks

Comment: Is there a particular reason for not using a model type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start by learning about conventions in ASP.NET MVC. You should use models for communicating between controllers and views.

Create a model type first:

```
public class SalaryModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Salary { get; set; }
}
```

Create your form by using HTML helpers and strongly typing your view:

```
@model SalaryModel

<div id="mydiv">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Game", FormMethod.Post, new { @Id = "Form1" }))
{
    <table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>Name :</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(item => item.Name)</td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>Salary :</td>
        <td><input name="salary" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">@Html.TextBoxFor(item => item.Salary)</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
}
</div>
```

Then you can get the form values inside the model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(SalaryModel model)
{
    return View("Message");
}
```

There's a great [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/pluralsight-building-applications-with-aspnet-mvc-4) on ASP.NET MVC website that can help you with the basics.

Comment: how can i return partial view from action instead of regular view. give me small code. thanks

Comment: @Thomas return PartialView("PartialViewName") or PartialView("PartialViewName", model)

Comment: thanks. i always work with id attribute instead of name. when i remove name attribute and put id="name" & id="salary" then nothing is going to action method when i submit the form. any solution u have for working with id instead of name attribute of control. plzz help. thanks again

Comment: @Thomas Nope, model binding works with name attributes as far as I know. You can still override id attribute in HTML helpers.

Comment: thanks. how to override id attribute in HTML helpers. can u give me any example.

Comment: @Thomas @Html.TextBoxFor(item => item.Salary, new {id = "someCoolId"})

Comment: u write the code using a model type. so i like to know is there any special advantage for using a model type. i am new in mvc. so please help me to get idea & reason. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Change you controller

```
public ActionResult Save(string name, string salary)
{
    return View("Message");
}
```

As you have to use variable `name` which you have defined in `input`

```
<input name="name" type="text" />
<input name="salary" type="text" />
```

If you want to return partial view.

```
 return PartialView("Message", <<OptionalPartialViewModel>>);
```

Comment: how can i return partial view from action instead of regular view. give me small code. thanks

Comment: @Thomas, You can go through these blog [Partial View in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/617361/Partial-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-4) and [ASP .NET MVC Partial Views](http://mvc4beginner.com/Tutorial/MVC-Partial-Views.html)

Comment: thanks. i always work with id attribute instead of name. when i remove name attribute and put id="name" & id="salary" then nothing is going to action method when i submit the form. any solution u have for working with id instead of name attribute of control. plzz help. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

MVC Bind form inputs to `Action` by their **names**. You should change your method params as the same of the form. Also, you are missing the `HttpPost` attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(string name, string salary)
{
    /*Do Stuff here*/

    return View("Message");
}
```